# parse.com - How to generate and add verification url within email?

Tags: javascript, android, email, parse-platform

I am using parse.com as backend for my android application.

On signup, an email is sent to user with the help of my parse cloud code and mailgun api integration. My code works fine for sending email.

But I am unable to understand how to add an auto-generated url within my mail, to verify the user's email address and save that information in the parse database.

What i have tried is, turning on email verification option, but don't know what to do next. Also, I am using my own domain for sending email and not parse one. Would really appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Goto your dashboard-> App Settings-> Hosting and Email. There you will able to find Email Settings. Enable "Verify User Emails" . DONE

Comment: Yeah, I have already done that. How to link it with my signup? I am using findInBackground to check if username already exists and a custom table (not User one).